# Invalid Instance definition. Only one autoincrement field allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
const Category = sequelize.define("category",{

    categoryid:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement:false,
        allowNull:false,
        primeryKey:true
    },

const Blog = sequelize.define("blog",{
    blogid:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement:true,
        allowNull:false,
        primeryKey:true
    },
```

i want to create 2 tables but it gives error

i have 2 page blog and category and i called its on index.js but it gives error.

when i watch video his code  worked  but my code is not working

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the option `primaryKey` just fix the name (`primeryKey` -> `primaryKey`) and that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure there is only `one primary key in one table` because I can't see all the fields in each table. And adjust `primeryKey` to `primaryKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is not the **misspelling** of `primaryKey`, but the fact that `primaryKey` is **missing**.

If a column is marked `autoIncrement: true`, then it should also have `primaryKey: true`.